# Ajax Call Only Updates Page First Time

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've got a fairly simple timer which I set on one page and then view the countdown on another page.

The problem is that timer updates the first time but not again (unless I do a full page refresh which works but I want to avoid).
I don't have any errors in firebug.
The function resends the ajax command every 25 seconds - this works, I see the times coming through as expected.
If I change the time I can see the results back from the php page as expected however the timer itself doesn't update without an actual page refresh. 
I don't have any interaction with this page (its just a timer) so I can't update on click.

Any ideas what I'm missing? I know it must be obvious.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
suitcase();
});
setInterval(suitcase, 25000);

function suitcase() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'timeRTN.php',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    data: {            
        examlength: examlength
    },
    success: function(examlength) {
        $('#pauseResume').countdown({
            until: examlength,
            format: 'HMS'
        })
      },
     })
    };
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pauseResume" class="countdown"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What does `$().countdown()` do?

Comment: @Ghommey I guess it draws the countdown. Good pointer though.

Comment: Old IE doesn't support a comma at the end of an object literal. Not the cause though

Comment: Try moving `setInterval` inside the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`.

Comment: You might not be able to create the same counter twice. You might need to kill the previous instance and `replace` with a new countdown.

Comment: Is this the library you are using? http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#optionset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Suitcase(){
var countdownExists = false;
...
  success: function(examlength) {
    if(!countdownExists){
      $('#pauseResume').countdown({
        until: examlength,
        format: 'HMS'
      })
      countdownExists = true;
    }else{
      $('#pauseResume').countdown('option',{
        until: examlength,
        format: 'HMS'
    })
```

Documentation here:
http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html

`$().countdown(options)` creates a new instance of a countdown

`$().countdown('option', options)` sets the options of an existing instance.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I couldn't get your code working (even adding/tweaking 'option' didn't want to update) but you got me on the right track. I thought I was looking for something wrong with the updating of the div but going back to the original docs I saw way at the bottom of the page $(selector).countdown('destroy') I destroy the existing one and then recreate it on the next line. Probably not as intended by the author but it works and no more screen refreshing